# Display custom properties in Address Book template

Tags: cocoa, addressbook

I created a new custom property for a ABPerson. It's value can be retrieved with    valueForProperty:@"my.property", but I'm struggeling to figure out how to make it available in the template file to be viewed in a contact using Address Book, such as Firstname, Lastname etc...

Does anybody have a hint or an idea how I can achieve this? I would also like to add a second image to a contact and display it. Is this actually possible to display within Address Book?